Endogeneity or omitted variable bias in a causal model
I am estimating a regression of the form:

My variable of interest is "X1", and based on the information here I can confidently say that the goal of my analysis is a causal inference.
Now to my question. Say "Y" is the "number of dogs per country". This variable was estimated by a well-known organization and they involved a bunch of experts. However, the original expert estimation was not of the "no. of dogs per country" but of the "share of dogs by population by region" (in other words, they estimated that in region A the no. of dogs is 5% of the population, in region B it's 10%, etc.). From this % estimation, they estimated the "Y" I am using at the country level (so the Y varies by country, but largely based on the regional estimates of the %).
If I add "region" as a control variable, I would be introducing endogeneity to the model, wouldn't I? (as region literally defines "Y"). But, not including it could also be OVB? Which of the two is more problematic in this scenario?
I don't know if this matters, but the adjusted R2 goes from 0.30 without the regional dummies to 0.88 with the regional dummies.

I don't know if this matters, but the R2 goes from .30 without the regional dummies to .88 with the regional dummies. Welcome to Cross Validated! Does this refer to the adjusted or unadjusted $R^2?$ If this is the unadjusted $R^2$, what are the values of adjusted $R^2?$

@Dave this is the adjusted R2! The unadjusted would be .35 and .90
